# Using stream for Mongoose query really worth it?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

If I have a query like this:

```js
//sample 1 conventional querying
const response =  await Events.find({data: {$gt: new Date('2019-12-01')}})
res.json(response)

//sample 2 using stream
Events.find({data: {$gt: new Date('2019-12-01')}})
    .cursor()
    .pipe(JSONStream.stringify())
    .pipe(res.type('json'))
```

When I should to use each one? And what the advantages of using streaming?

Answer (score 6):

Well simplest explanation is -

When you have little data returned from your find query - You could consider loading it in memory and use it.

When you have large data - You should use streams so that you don't need to store the complete data in memory which might make nodejs throw out of memoruy exception. You could override that but not a good idea.

Hope it clears.